# How to throw error from the list of values in trigger in salesforce?

Tags: apex, trigger

I have written a trigger logic in that I want to throw the error from trigger, but its not working.

```
for(Case cs : cases){
   ............
   ............  
 }

        if(contactIds.size() > 0){
            List<Case> caseList = [SELECT Id, Contact.Name,contactId 
                                FROM Case
                               WHERE CreatedDate = THIS_QUARTER 
                                AND isOldRequest__c='Yes'
                                AND ContactId IN :contactIds];
            if(caseList.size() > 20){
                for(Case c : caseList){
                    c.addError('XXXXXXX');
                } 
            }
        }
```

c.addError('XXXXXXX'); Doesn't throw error. I dont want that Contact to create 21st record if its a OldRequest.

Comment: First, you are executing a SOQL query in a for loop which is a bad practice. You should start by reading this [tutorial](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Trigger_Frameworks_and_Apex_Trigger_Best_Practices). Then, are you sure the size of your caseList is superior to 20?

Comment: When used on Trigger.new in before insert and before update triggers, and on Trigger.old in before delete triggers, the error message is displayed in the application interface.

Comment: Oh yes sorry. The indentation fooled me.

Comment: @NITHESH K - I dont understood, Could you please show some code? I am using `Trigger.new`, `Trigger.oldMap`, but still not working ! `trigger CaseTrigger on Case (before insert, before update, after update)`

Comment: Can u add more code from where you getting cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add directly **addError** method to **Case** once you received from trigger.new it will work. something like this.

Normally this is the way Trigger Exception will work

```
trigger CaseException on Case(before insert,before update) {
    for(Case c : trigger.new)
    {
        if(c.isOldRequest__c ==null) // some condition on your requirement
        {
          c.addError('please insert the field');
        }
    }
}
```

Your below code will not work because your **caseList** not under the scope of **trigger insert or update**. No where else your **inserting** or **updating** again those SOQL **caseList**. unless your insert or update on those object it will not trigger any exception on those SOQL object.

> ```
>  if(contactIds.size() > 0){
>                 List<Case> caseList = [SELECT Id, Contact.Name,contactId 
>                                     FROM Case
>                                    WHERE CreatedDate = THIS_QUARTER 
>                                     AND isOldRequest__c='Yes'
>                                     AND ContactId IN :contactIds];
>                 if(caseList.size() > 20){
>                     for(Case c : caseList){
>                         c.addError('XXXXXXX');
>                     } 
>                 }
>             }
> ```

Trigger exception is raised when **addError** method is present on **Trigger.new or Trigger.old** Objects when u inserting,updating and delete the objects.

[You can refer some question Arise in stack](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/132025/show-error-message-from-custom-exception-on-standand-page-in-trigger-handler)

[More about addError](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_addError)

Comment: Hey, Thanks I just tackle the condition, as per your guidance, its working now

Comment: You have to add your "addError" to SObject you received from Trigger, After  trigger is going insert only those record. Not the record your SOQL in trigger.

Comment: Could you please show some code for better understanding ?

Comment: @user4567570 Your Welcome ..